# Unsupported Operating System and Failed to connect to MySQL

Tags: installation, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install MySQL but I get the following warning:

[image]

I have a Mac and its installed the latest version 11.6 , so I don't understand why it says its not supported.
After that warning I tried to install a connection to MySQL server and I get an error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is running?

Comment: I downloaded not the last version, but the second last and now everything work perfect. Still not get what was wrong in the beginning though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded not the last version, but the second last and now everything it's fine. I know its not a "nice" solution but now I have no warning message and I successfully made an SQL connection.

The version I downloaded is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that MySQL has different versions for different OS, and keep in mind that different OS have different flavours. For example...

macOS has these different versions for macOS X:

- Yosemite
- El Captain
- Sierra
- High Sierra
- Mojave

and so on...

I am currently using this version from the date of this post: [My current macOS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkBuQ.png)

And I stumbled upon the same issue when installing MySQL and the Workbench, after several failed attempts and YouTube tutorials to successfully download MySQL; so here is my best advice on how to download MySQL & the Workbench.

### First Step: Installing MySQL/MySQL Server

1. Find the up-to-date version of your macOS system from their Download website, by clicking Downloads from their official website and selecting ***"MySQL Community (GPL) Downloads"***.
2. Then click on **MySQL Community Server**
3. At this current time, the up-to-date version of MySQL is: [MySQL Community Server 8.1.0 Innovation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cymzs.png), obviously for the macOS version, this will only be compatible with: [macOS 13 ARM or macOS 13 x86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BAQ7.png), this will be the Ventura version. So it will be pointless installing this version if your macOS system version is older, and it will not be compatible, even if you successfully installed it on your system, IT WILL NOT WORK.
4. So use the version that is compatible with your system. In my case, my macOS version is the **macOS Big Sur** *Version: 11.7.9*, so the MySQL version that I went for is the up-to-date version for my system; I did this by selecting: [Archives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTI25.png)
5. Then the *Product Version*, is what you choose appropriately to your system's version; [Product Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/docrf.png), the note displayed under the version selections tells you which version the product is compatible with: [Product Version Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zY4O.png). Think of it this way... "Packages for Big Sur (11) are compatible with Monterey (12)", so the product package, is for **"Big Sur (11)"**, but it is also ***"compatible with Monterey (12)"***. Some will say ***"Packages for Monterey (12) are compatible with ..."*** or ***"Packages for Ventura (13) are compatible with ..."*** or ***"Packages for High Sierra (10.13) are compatible with ..."*** etc; so choose the Product Version that is compatible but also up-to-date to your system's version.

### Second Step: Installing MySQL Workbench

Going back to their community downloads website, click **Downloads** and select the ***"MySQL Community (GPL) Downloads"***.

1. In this case choose the **MySQL Workbench**
2. Follow the same protocol for **Installing MySQL/MySQL Server**, by selecting **Archives**, and choose the **Product Version** the same as the **Product Version**, when installing **MySQL/MySQL Server**. So in my case, I chose this: [MySQL Workbench version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIkNw.png) which was the same version as when I installed **MySQL/MySQL Server**. If you don't/cannot find the same product version as that with the MySQL/MySQL Server, my guess *(and literally)* is to download a version lower than the product version that you installed for the MySQL/MySQL Server. Because your best chance is that the Workbench may not be up-to-date to your system's version, but will/should be compatible with your system version.

The mistake that I made, when installing the Workbench for the first time, was installing a newer version of it, which resulted in the question that you originally posted - **"Unsupported Operating System"**. And after installing other previous newer versions of the workbench, I got the same message, until I installed the same version for the Workbench as I had with the **MySQL/MySQL Server**.

---

#### NOTES: After Successful Installation (Hopefully!)

You will need to set the **PATH** of your installation to your bash profile, as `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`, you can find your MySQL Path, below your **System Preferences**, and the icon for MySQL should be visible. Select this, and this should open your MySQL ***Instances/Configuration*** page.

Select ***Configuration***, and copy the path here seen in the *Base Directory*, paste this on your bash profile, as I have explained above. This will enable you to access MySQL terminal easily, by inputting the command `mysql -u root -p`. For general help with using MySQL terminal visit their website, or type:

`mysql [--help|-I|-?]` to refer to their terminal commands.